# How to Make Dropdown menu scrollable in tailwind flowbite?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, flowbite

This is the flowbite code I want to make the dropdown scrollable, how do I do that? I just added overflow-auto in the class but it changed nothing, here is the code:

```
<button id="dropdownHoverButton" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdownHover" data-dropdown-trigger="hover" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800" type="button">Dropdown hover <svg class="w-4 h-4 ml-2" aria-hidden="true" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"></path></svg></button>
<!-- Dropdown menu -->
<div id="dropdownHover" class="z-10 hidden overflow-auto bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700">
    <ul class="py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" aria-labelledby="dropdownHoverButton">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Sign out</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the menu a height, otherwise it will expand to accommodate its children. In tailwind, you can do that with the `h-{number}` class.

```
<div id="dropdownHover" class="z-10 h-10 overflow-auto bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700">
```

Comment: How can I add live code show in my question? teach me so that viewers will see it

Comment: For Tailwind you can use something like https://play.tailwindcss.com/ and share a link. But remember to always also add the code itself in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<Dropdown class='overflow-auto h-{some value}>'
```

will make it